# How to get User Identity in Cordova or Hybrid project?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

How can I get User ID. which uniquely identifies a user on that particular device in Hybrid or Cordova application,

Are there any plugins which I can use? What I am actually looking is something like.

This is precisely what you get in list of permission you would be asked which you generally install apps.

where Identity is -

An app can use your account and/or profile information on your device. Identity access may include the ability to:

Find accounts on the device
Read your own contact card (example: name and contact information)
Modify your own contact card
Add or remove accounts

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use this PhoneGap/Cordova plugin:

https://github.com/Paldom/UniqueDeviceID

Comment: Thank you Del, I will give it a try!